# react-native-google-signin is not working in React-native 0.60

Tags: javascript, google-play-services, react-native

I have upgraded my project to React-native 0.60 and now I can't sign in with google.
I am using the react-native-google-signin library. Please help.

below are the versions I am using:
library version - 2.0.0 also tried it with the previous version.
React-Native version- 0.60.4
react version - 16.8.6

Please help me with the solution. Thanks

Comment: Have you any specific error? Have you tried a previous version of the library? Or at least, version 0.59 of React Native?

Comment: please, can you share the error or what you have done with your code? if it was react-native issue, please open it here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

Comment: There are no errors in the log